# Get Signing time(time stamp) of a digital Signature using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, digital-signature

I have certain DLL and Exe , I have used powershell to check whether the file is digitally signed or not,
Now what I want is to get the Time Stamp (Signing Time)  of the digital Signature i.e whn the file was signed?
How to get this information in powershell??
Thanks in advance

Comment: The timestamp is a signed attribute in the CMS structure of the digital signature.

Comment: @eugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I want to get this attribute from powershell script ,,  I want to get the signing time,, n how to do that with powershell?

Comment: Maybe write some PowerShell module that will do the job? You can use our SecureBlackbox .NET edition for writing such module.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to this so far is described here:

http://en-us.sysadmins.lv/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=27

(Thank you Vadims Podans!!!)

Just put the following code in a ps1 script and then call the function at the end, providing the path to the file you want to check:

```
#==================================================
function Get-AuthenticodeSignatureEx {
<#
.ForwardHelpTargetName Get-AuthenticodeSignature
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String[]]$FilePath
    )
    begin {
$signature = @"
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptQueryObject(
    int dwObjectType,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pvObject,
    int dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
    int dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
    int dwFlags,
    ref int pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
    ref int pdwContentType,
    ref int pdwFormatType,
    ref IntPtr phCertStore,
    ref IntPtr phMsg,
    ref IntPtr ppvContext
);
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptMsgGetParam(
    IntPtr hCryptMsg,
    int dwParamType,
    int dwIndex,
    byte[] pvData,
    ref int pcbData
);
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptMsgClose(
    IntPtr hCryptMsg
);
[DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CertCloseStore(
    IntPtr hCertStore,
    int dwFlags
);
"@
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
        Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32
    }
    process {
        Get-AuthenticodeSignature @PSBoundParameters | ForEach-Object {
            $Output = $_
            if ($Output.SignerCertificate -ne $null) {
                $pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType =  0
                $pdwContentType =  0
                $pdwFormatType =  0
                [IntPtr]$phCertStore = [IntPtr]::Zero
                [IntPtr]$phMsg = [IntPtr]::Zero
                [IntPtr]$ppvContext = [IntPtr]::Zero
                $return = [PKI.Crypt32]::CryptQueryObject(
                    1,
                    $Output.Path,
                    16382,
                    14,
                    $null,
                    [ref]$pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
                    [ref]$pdwContentType,
                    [ref]$pdwFormatType,
                    [ref]$phCertStore,
                    [ref]$phMsg,
                    [ref]$ppvContext
                )
                $pcbData = 0
                $return = [PKI.Crypt32]::CryptMsgGetParam($phMsg,29,0,$null,[ref]$pcbData)
                $pvData = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList $pcbData
                $return = [PKI.Crypt32]::CryptMsgGetParam($phMsg,29,0,$pvData,[ref]$pcbData)
                $SignedCms = New-Object Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms
                $SignedCms.Decode($pvData)
                foreach ($Infos in $SignedCms.SignerInfos) {
                    foreach ($CounterSignerInfos in $Infos.CounterSignerInfos) {
                        $sTime = ($CounterSignerInfos.SignedAttributes | ?{$_.Oid.Value -eq "1.2.840.113549.1.9.5"}).Values | `
                        Where-Object {$_.SigningTime -ne $null}
                    }
                }
                $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SigningTime -Value $sTime.SigningTime.ToLocalTime() -PassThru -Force
                [void][PKI.Crypt32]::CryptMsgClose($phMsg)
                [void][PKI.Crypt32]::CertCloseStore($phCertStore,0)
            } else {
                $Output
            }
        }
    }
    end {}
}

Get-AuthenticodeSignatureEx .\wsusscn2.cab | FL *





#==================================================
```

The output should give you all the info, including:

SigningTime            : 08-04-2014 09:27:2

Hope it helps!

Comment: I got the following error when running the latest statement on a explorer.exe
> Get-AuthenticodeSignatureEx .\explorer.exe | FL * You cannot call a
    > method on a null-valued expression. At line:82 char:17
    > + ...             $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Signi ...
    > +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    >     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    >     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with Vadims Podans script.

I did find that [SigCheck.exe from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) provides the **Signing Date** (and time)

`Sigcheck.exe -c -nobanner -w FileSig.csv .\MyFile.exe`

Here's a PowerShell wrapper function using SigCheck

```
Function Get-FileSigTimestamp {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateScript({ Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf })][String]$FilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][ValidateScript({ Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf })][String]$SigCheckFullPath = '.\Sigcheck.exe'
)
$TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
& $SigCheckFullPath -c -nobanner -w "$TempFile" "$FilePath"
$FileSig = Import-Csv -Path $TempFile
$FileSigDate = [datetime]$FileSig.Date
Remove-Item -Path $TempFile
If ($FileSigDate -is [datetime] -and $FileSig.Verified -eq 'Signed') {
    Write-Verbose -Message 'File Signature Date determined'
    Return $FileSigDate
} Else {
    $File = Get-Item -Path $FilePath
    Write-Verbose -Message 'File Signature Date does not exist or could not be determined.  Returning file modified timestamp'
    Return $File.LastWriteTime
}    }
```